# ¿como hago un hilo de correo con otra ya enviado anteriormente con yagamil'

Tags: python

estoy utilizando la libreria Yagmail para python; quiero saber como hago un hilo de correo con otro ya enviado anteriormente con yagamil?, he consultado y me dicen que obteniendo el id del mensaje, pero he intentado diferentes formas y nunca obtengo el id, siempr eme sale error

este es una parte del codigo

```
yag.send(to=destinatario, subject=asunto, contents=contenido)

# Obtiene el ID del mensaje
mensaje_id = yag.message_id
```

el ejecutarlo me sale este errro AttributeError: `'SMTP' object has no attribute 'message_id'`.

muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!